# Build & start hybris 5.1.1 on Linux or Mac OS X

Tags: bash, unix, sap-commerce-cloud

I am installing the hybris 5.1.1 complete package **for the first time** & according to the procedure of this web page:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Quick+Installation

However, when I perform the step:

> *On Unix-related systems (such as Linux or Mac OS X), run
>   setantenv.sh by entering ./setantenv.sh.*

by...

> *mlittle-mbook1-2:platform mlittle$ ./setantenv.sh*

I get the message...

> *-bash: ./setantenv.sh: Permission denied*

I have also tried setting to execute permissions with `chmod 755 platform`, but it did not work..

Comment: Stack overflow is here for specific questions regarding development and code. Try taking your question a different stack exchange, like https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try `. ./setantenv.sh` to set ant environment. Then `ant clean all` and `sh hybrisserver.sh`. After staring server, initialize system.

Comment: Thank you to all who answered as that helped. I finally got it installed. The guidance was in-correct. It was as Shreshtt suggested, it should have been . ./setantenv.sh.

Answer (score 7):

You have you use the bash command

`. ./setantenv.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `. ./setenv.sh` since it sets maven environment as well

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ls -l
```

To see who the owner and who the group is. If you are not the owner or in the group, you may need to change your permissions to 777 or 775 respectively.

Prefacing your statement with sudo is frequently necessary to write files to folders such as /bin for the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

the "Permission denied" error means you do not have permission to execute the shell program.

You will need to change the file mode to allow execution.

Here's the command(The steps below assumes you are the owner of the file):

```
chmod 755 ./setantenv.sh
```

then run

```
. ./setantenv.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First change the ownership of all files of your Hybris installation, to your current user.

> ```
> hybris : ~ $ whoami 
> hybris
> hybris : ~ chown -R hybris: ./
> hybris : ~ chmod -R 755 ./
> ```

2. Then run the setantenv command

> hybris : ~/hybris/bin/platform $ . setantenv.sh